# Adding a caption to a tcolorbox \tcblisting

Tags: listings, captions, tcolorbox

I'm new to the whole `TeX` world and have finally managed creating my own `tcolorbox` code box:

[image: sample box]

Now I would like to caption my code boxes like regular listings.
It should say something like "Code-Snippet 1: Sample Box" **below** the `tcolorbox`, similar to this figure:

[image: caption]

How would I do this? Is there a way to `\caption` the `tcblisting`?
Any help would by greatly appreciated and I've added a minimal working example of my box as well:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{ngerman}                   
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage[scaled=.95]{inconsolata}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, breakable, skins}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\makebox[3em][r]{\ifnum\value{lstnumber}<10 0\fi\the\value{lstnumber}}}

\newtcblisting{ccode}
{colback=bg,
colframe=black!70,
enhanced,
listing only,
overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
        rectangle ([xshift=5.1mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
listing options={numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,   basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, xleftmargin=0.6em, language = c, aboveskip=\smallskipamount, belowskip=\smallskipamount}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{ccode}
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    stub;
}
\end{ccode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want `floating` listings?

Comment: I'd prefer floating listings but as a beginner I have to tackle one problem at the time. If you can provide a `floating` and `captioned` solution you'd totally save my day.

Comment: `ngerman` is actually a little bit outdated. Use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` rather

Comment: have you tried `\usepackage{caption}` and then `\captionof`?

Comment: @naphaneal: That would not work, I fear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**update**

[image]

I don't think it's possible to use a `\caption` without much redefinitions. Here's a version with `blend into=listings`, which must be done in `\AtBeginDocument` or after `\begin{document}`.

The `title=` will then be used as the long caption text, the short one is given by `list text=...` -- See the example, please.

To move the caption to the bottom, the title has to be detached and the title box reconfigured.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage[scaled=.95]{inconsolata}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\tcbuselibrary{listings, breakable, skins}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\makebox[3em][r]{\ifnum\value{lstnumber}<10 0\fi\the\value{lstnumber}}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\newtcblisting[blend into=listings]{ccode}[1][]{%
  colback=bg,
  colframe=black!70,
  enhanced,
  listing only,
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
      rectangle ([xshift=5.1mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
  listing remove caption=false,
  listing options={numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,   
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, 
    xleftmargin=0.6em, 
    language = c, 
    aboveskip=\smallskipamount, 
    belowskip=\smallskipamount, 
  },
  coltitle=black,
  attach boxed title to bottom center={yshift=-10pt},
  boxed title style={enhanced jigsaw, colback=white, sharp corners, boxrule=0pt},
  #1
}
}
\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\begin{ccode}[list text={C-Programm!},title={Ein primitives C - Programm!}]
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    stub;
}
\end{ccode}
\end{document}
```

`tcolorbox` defines `listing remove caption=true`, i.e use this as an option and provide a caption argument, i.e. define the `\newtcblisting` with a mandatory argument`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
%\usepackage{ngerman}                   
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage[scaled=.95]{inconsolata}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, breakable, skins}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\makebox[3em][r]{\ifnum\value{lstnumber}<10 0\fi\the\value{lstnumber}}}

\newtcblisting{ccode}[2][]
{colback=bg,
colframe=black!70,
enhanced,
listing only,
overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)
    rectangle ([xshift=5.1mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
    listing remove caption=false,
listing options={numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,   basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, xleftmargin=0.6em, language = c, aboveskip=\smallskipamount, belowskip=\smallskipamount, caption={#2}},#1
}
\begin{document}

\begin{ccode}{Ein primitives C - Programm!}
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    stub;
}
\end{ccode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Christian, this has been helpful already. But with your example the caption is inside of the box and there seems no way to move it. I'd prefer having it below the box, so it looks just like usual listings and figures. I've updated my sample picture.

Comment: @Raito: That's why we want to have the clear question right from the beginning, not updates :-( Now, all my efforts are useless

Comment: I stated that I wanted the caption **below** the tcolorbox right from the very beginning. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear enough - I added the better picture when I saw that you misunderstood me. :( Still learned from your example, so not useless at all.

Comment: @Raito: See the update, please

Comment: @Raito: You're welcome -- and sorry about missing the `below` feature in the first trial